# $\left(\arctan x\right)^2=1+\frac{\pi^2}{16}-x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$$(\alpha>\beta)$ are two values of $x$ satisfying the equation $\left(\arctan x\right)^2=1+\frac{\pi^2}{16}-x^2$.Find the value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the solutions of $\left(\arctan x\right)^2=1+\frac{\pi^2}{16}-x^2$.

$\left(\arctan \alpha\right)^2=1+\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\alpha^2$....(1)

$\left(\arctan \beta\right)^2=1+\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\beta^2$....(2)

Adding the two equations,

$\left(\arctan \alpha\right)^2+\left(\arctan \beta\right)^2=2+\frac{\pi^2}{8}-\alpha^2-\beta^2$

There seems to be no path from here.Please guide me.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a solution then $-\alpha$ is a solution. So $\alpha+\beta=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problems like this are (in general) impossible to solve exactly, but in certain instances there might a trick to exploit.  Rewrite the equation as $$(\arctan x)^2 - 1 = \left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right)^2 - x^2.$$ Can you find a solution if both sides are equal to some particular fixed value?